# How to start programming a Touchscreen LCD Monitor?

Tags: touchscreen, kiosk

We had a research about doing different programs using different platforms. And it came to my mind that developing a Kiosk or Touchscreen monitor can be one of my options.
My plan is to develop a 3D tour of a restaurant, it should be able to control the tour,, a user can have a tour using the touchscreen monitor..

What is the best programming language to use?
Can anyone give me an insight of how I will start doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very open-ended question, and what you're describing is a pretty difficult thing to build if you haven't had any experience doing so before. In general, I'd recommend contacting a contractor with experience building systems like this if you want to get the best result.

To answer your question, though: many kiosk systems simply run Adobe Flash Player, which [can do some rudimentary 3D](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/3d-cameras.html), but probably the most purpose-built tool for this use is [Adobe Director](http://www.adobe.com/products/director/), which can import 3D models and is often used to make casual 3D games.

Here are some links to get you started with Director 3D:

- http://www.adobe.com/support/director/3d_basics.html
- http://www.directorforum.com/showthread.php?t=645

If you don't have the restaurant already rendered in 3D, you may be able to build something relatively quickly using [Trimble SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/) (formerly Google SketchUp; Director can import its output natively).

Comment: I'm so sorry sir, I didnt mean to ask an open ended question, it's just that i still dont have any idea of what to ask.

Thanks for the links, this will help a lot.

But I would like to ask another question, sir.
Will it be the same if I coded the program using ordinary codes? I mean, will it work for a Touchscreen monitor?

Comment: @JetPro: sure; a touch screen kiosk is normally just a standard PC and a USB input device (kind of a special type of mouse), so you could build it using Java, .NET, or HTML and Javascript if you like. You might be interested to look up some of Microsoft's new Windows 8 Metro options which are designed from the get-go for touchscreen use.